# Simple TCP scan with Go

Tags: go, port-scanning

I am learning to use Golang to develop hacking tools through [Blackhat-Go](https://nostarch.com/blackhatgo) and port scan **scanme.nmap.org** on Windows and Linux while doing TCP scanning.Here's my code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "sort"
)

func worker(ports, result chan int) {
    for port := range ports {
        address := fmt.Sprintf("scanme.nmap.org:%d", port)
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", address)
        if err != nil {
            result <- 0
            continue
        }
        conn.Close()
        result <- port
    }
}

func main() {
    ports := make(chan int, 100)
    result := make(chan int)
    var openport []int

    for i := 0; i < cap(ports); i++ {
        go worker(ports, result)
    }

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 1024; i++ {
            ports <- i
        }
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 1024; i++ {
        port := <-result
        if port != 0 {
            openport = append(openport, port)
        }
    }

    close(ports)
    close(result)
    sort.Ints(openport)

    for _, value := range openport {
        fmt.Printf("%d open\n", value)
    }
}
```

Running on Windows shows that port 25 is open.

```
22 open
25 open 
80 open 
110 open
```

However, port 25 is not detected on Linux.

```
22 open
80 open 
110 open
```

I used NMAP to scan and found that the state of port 25 is Filtered.

`25/tcp  filtered  smtp`

Why is port 25 detected on Windows.

any help please.

Comment: Is it detected as open when you run it from the windows machine itself?

Comment: When I use net. Dial to connect on Windows, err's value is nil

Comment: Is it detected as open when you run it from the windows machine itself?

Comment: yes,I use net.Dial to make a TCP connection and determine if the return value is nil. When I run it on a Windows PC, it shows port 25 open     @zerkms

Comment: I'm guessing this is not due to go at all,  since nmap agrees.   You should ask on super user or server fault.  Especially if windows nmap behaves like windows go,  because then your program is out of the equation

Comment: @L2ksy0d so, what if it's open for local connections only? What actually is a problem? It's not a surprise that sometimes ports are open from one host and not open for another host :shrug:

Comment: @L2ksy0d : if you still have the issue today, perhaps check what error is returned ?